# Why is the real estate excise tax referred to as an excise tax instead of a sale tax in the United States?

Tags: united-states, taxes, terminology, sales-tax, washington

In real estate in the United States, local and state governments [may](https://www.masterclass.com/articles/what-is-an-excise-tax-explained) levy a real estate excise tax (or REET) on the sale of real property. E.g., in [Washington](https://dor.wa.gov/taxes-rates/other-taxes/real-estate-excise-tax), the excise tax is as follows (as of 2021-10-10):

| Sale price thresholds | Tax rate |
| --- | --- |
| $500,000 or less | 1.10% |
| $500,000.01 - $1,500,000 | 1.28% |
| $1,500,000.01 - $3,000,000 | 2.75% |
| $3,000,000.01 or more | 3% |

(in addition to some [local REET](https://dor.wa.gov/sites/default/files/legacy/Docs/forms/RealEstExcsTx/RealEstExTxRates_1_20.pdf)  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210714030054/https://dor.wa.gov/sites/default/files/legacy/Docs/forms/RealEstExcsTx/RealEstExTxRates_1_20.pdf)))

I read from https://www.freshbooks.com/hub/taxes/an-excise-tax

> What Is the Difference Between an Excise Tax and a Sales Tax?
>
> Sales tax is the tax that businesses usually collect from the consumer at the point of purchase and pay to the government for the sale of certain goods and services. There are **two basic differences between sales tax and excise tax**.
>
> While **excise tax is levied only on certain goods and services that are considered harmful or linked to specific health issues**, sales tax is applied to a broad range of things.
>
> Also, **sales tax is calculated a percentage of the sale price**. For example, if you buy a more expensive luxury vehicle as opposed to a cheaper utility vehicle, you would need to pay more sales tax. The percentage of sales tax applied is set by the local and state governments in the United States.
>
> On the other hand, **an excise tax is often a per unit tax imposed before the purchase price for specific items by the state**, local and federal governments. For example, in 2019 a tax of $4.35 is imposed on each 20 cigarette package by the New York State regardless of the base price of the pack.

The real estate excise tax in Washington is both a percentage on the sale and on a harmless item. According to the definitions quoted above, this sounds like a sale tax and not an excise tax.

Why is the real estate excise tax referred to as an excise tax instead of a sale tax in the United States?

Comment: Why is the name given to a tax a matter of concern for _Personal_ Finance and Money?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Why do you think there's a terminology tag for Personal Finance and Money?

Comment: Because lawyers and politicians?

Comment: It's technically the "Real Estate Transfer Tax" in my state, colloquially called "the stamp tax" by real estate agents and title agents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In other United States states, it's colloquially referred to as a [stamp tax](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/stampduty.asp)

> Stamp duty is the tax governments place on legal documents, usually in the transfer of assets or property. Governments impose stamp duties, also known as stamp taxes, on documents that are needed to legally record certain types of transactions. This includes legal documents recording marriages, military commissions, and the sale or transfer of a property.

Historically, goods subject to excise tax, [like alcohol](https://www.drinksplanet.com/dating-us-bottles-via-tax-stamps...-1205.html), would be marked with a [physical stamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excise_stamp) to show that the duty had been paid.

The stamp tax or excise tax refer to a transaction that the government has provided itself a monopoly on charging for proof of payment.

Answer (score 3):

As [jamesqf](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/24392/jamesqf) and [Fattie](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/41786/fattie) mentioned in the comment section, the choice of referring to the real estate tax as an excise tax stems from an arbitrary decision from the lawmakers and politicians. Since an excise tax tends to be levied on certain goods and services that are considered harmful or linked to specific health issues, it is more politically admissible to raise excise taxes than sales taxes.

Another example of a tax dubiously labeled as an excise tax is the newly introduced tax on long-term capital gains in Washington state, which [wasn't well received](https://www.king5.com/amp/article/news/politics/elections/voters-get-a-voice-on-washingtons-capital-gains-tax/281-2e092f76-83ee-4989-ab38-4063c5bff903):

> McKenna's lawsuit claims the law is unconstitutional by labeling the capital gains tax as an excise tax – which the group says are typically taxes on privileges like owning a business or transactions on gas, cigarettes or alcohol – instead of an income tax. "If this is an excise tax, it’s an illegal one,” McKenna said in a statement.